# Problem with jQuery AJAX login (JSON parse fail)

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, captcha

I have a problem with my jQuery AJAX login. When i try to login in the console pops up a message "**Requested JSON parse failed.**". The main purpose of the code is a login to admin dashboard protected by simple jQuery slide captcha, because I don't like the reCAPTCHA. Thats my jQuery AJAX call:

```
$(".slidercaptcha").hide();
    $( "#login" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".beforeContinue").hide();
        $(".slidercaptcha").fadeIn('fast');
    });
    var Toast = Swal.mixin({
        toast: true,
        position: 'top-end',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 4000
    });
    var captcha = sliderCaptcha({
        id: 'captcha',
        repeatIcon: 'fa fa-redo',
        onSuccess: function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax_requests/login_ajax.php',
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    'username': $('#username').val(),
                    'password': $('#password').val()
                },
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function(response) {

                    Toast.fire({
                        icon: 'success',
                        title: "Successfully logged in! Redirecting..."
                    });

                    setTimeout(function() {

                        if (response.status == "1") {

                            location.href = "index.php";

                        } else if (response.status == "2") {

                            location.href = "index.php";

                        } else {

                            Toast.fire({
                                icon: 'error',
                                title: "Something went wrong, please try again later!"
                            });

                        }

                    }, 2000);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                    var msg = '';
                    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                        msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
                    } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                        msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
                    } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                        msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
                    } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                        msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
                    } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                        msg = 'Time out error.';
                    } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                        msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
                    } else {
                        msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
                    }
                    console.log(msg);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

And thats my PHP form (**login_ajax.php**):

```
<?php header('Content-Type: application/json');
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","shopperapproved");

$username = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$password_crypted = hash('sha256', $conn->real_escape_string($password));

$_login = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `admin_users` WHERE `username`=? AND `password`=?");
$_login->bind_param("ss", $username, $password_crypted);
$_login->execute();
if ($_login->num_rows > 0) {
$_SESSION['login_session'] = hash('sha256', rand(6453, 891673));
if (isset($_SESSION['login_session'])) {
    $result = array("status" => "1");
    echo json_encode($result);
} else {
    $result = array("status" => "0");
    echo json_encode($result);
}
} else {
$result = array("status" => "0");
echo json_encode($result);
}
$_login->close();
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What do you get back if you make:

```php
$res = json_encode($result);
print_r($res)
echo json_encode($result);
```

Check also in your ajax call:

```js
success: function(response) {
   var data = JSON.parse(response);
   console.log(data)
... your code
}
```

I think you json string is not right.

I saw in your code:

```php
if ($_login->execute()) {
```

So nothing will be executed

Example:

```php
$_login->execute();

$result = $_login->get_result();
$user   = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if ($user !== false) {
  $json = json_encode($user);
  print_r($json); // You should get back and Json String.
} else {
  // there where no results
}
```

Comment: Hey dude I got whats the problem. The problem is that the POST data from the form is not passing through and the PHP script is not collecting it. I realized that when i manually typed **$_POST['username'] = "admin"; and $_POST['password'] = "admin";** in the PHP script and it returned an array with the status. So how do make this POST data (username and password) go through the process? BTW from your php code i get back **SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data**

Comment: Updated my code. Try a JSON.parse like above.

Comment: I echo back an array with a status value which depends on the database records (does the username and password match). The status value could be **0** and **1**. **0** is wrong credentials and **1** is the information match.

Comment: No point trying to add this code in section **success: function(response)...** when the code doesn't even reach that section.

Comment: You make if ($_login->execute()) { so there is an if.....nothing will be executed.

Comment: My bad, I've saw my PHP mistake but nothing changes. Look at my updated code PHP code above.

Comment: As i said the problem comes from that the data is not passing through. The **$_POST['username'] and $_POST['password']** are not getting any values from the AJAX call.